# Han can I increase the time value in a setTimeout function when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function named showAlert that displays an alert. I have used the setTimeout function to delay it by 5 seconds. I have a button that should increase the delay by an additional 5 seconds. How can I do this?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Increment delay by 5 seconds</button>
    <script>
        var timer = 5000;
        function showAlert(){
            alert("Hello world");
        }
        setTimeout(showAlert, timer);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should happen if you click the button, wait 2 seconds, click the button again. Should the alert happen 5 seconds after your second click, or should it be additive where it should then wait 3(remainder from last timer) + 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to clear the timeout, calculate the new time until the callback should fire, and call `setTimeout` again.

I'll change the delay time to 1 second instead of 5 seconds to illustrate more quickly in the snippet below:

```js
let callbackTimestamp = Date.now() + 1000;

const cb = () => {
  timeoutId = null;
  console.log('hello');
};

let timeoutId = setTimeout(cb, 1000);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!timeoutId) return;
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  callbackTimestamp += 1000;
  timeoutId = setTimeout(cb, callbackTimestamp - Date.now());
});
```

```html
<button>Increment delay by 1 second</button>
```

(in your real code, change each `1000` to `5000`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, but you can cancel the previously scheduled job and start another.

```
<script>
    var job = undefined;
    function showAlert(){
        alert("Hello world");
    }
    function onButtonClick(){
        if (!!job) {
           clearTimeout(job);
        }
        job = setTimeout(showAlert, timer);
    }
</script>
```